# Best way to draw 3D text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, cocos2d-iphone

I need to draw two lines of text in a 3D perspective. They're not just flat characters, they are really 3D models and need to animate as well. Preferably with a glossy effect on them.

It sounds really complex to me and I have no experience with OpenGL. Are there frameworks that make this easy or am I looking at a difficult and timeconsuming task?

Comment: You are looking at a difficult and time-consuming task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cocos3d.  [cocos3d link here.](http://www.techipost.com/2011/02/20/installing-cocos3d-for-iphoneipad/)

Answer (score 0):

That kind of functionality on the iPhone requires plain OpenGL knowledge.  You'll need to learn OpenGL and implement all of this by yourself.  I know [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com) is being ported to iPhone but that's not done yet.  Good luck!